# Mercurial push, abort: authorization failed

Tags: apache, mercurial, https, apache2, repository

I'm having problems with pushing to mercurial repository:

```
$ hg push
pushing to https://user:***@hg.domain.com/X_repo
searching for changes
abort: authorization failed
```

The same URL (with the same credentials) is accessible through the web browser. Also, I tried it without embedding usr+pass into the URL.

HTTPS is correctly configured, I tried both Basic and Digest auth -- without a luck.

Pulling (through HTTP) works fine.

I'm using hgwebdir to serve my repo.

What else should I check?

I found this: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=2580
In my case it's not random, it happens every single time.

Relevant part of my vhost conf:

```
  WSGIScriptAlias  /  /home/(...)/hgwebdir.wsgi

  <Directory /home/(...)>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /(...)/basic-password
    AuthName (...)
    Require valid-user

    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

$ hg -v
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.0.2)
```

Strangely enough hg outgoing works ok:

```
$ hg outgoing
comparing with https://hg.domain.com/X_repo
http authorization required
realm: ...
user: ...
password: 
searching for changes
changeset:   64:...
tag:         tip
user:        ...
date:        ...
summary:     ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Problem turned out to be repo dir permissions. `chown www-data` solved it...

Comment: Don't forget that you also need allow_push in the [web] section of your .hg/hgrc

Comment: $ sudo chown -R wwwrun:www /srv/www/htdocs/hg/reposfrom https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep Section 7, for those not so good with linux.

Comment: For those using Ubuntu:  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/hg/repos

Comment: Even I put the owner ship to 'www-data' I still have the problem:password:
sending [================================================================================>] 6/6 01sabort: authorization failed

Comment: To check for the apache user on the system, have a look at /etc/passwd

Answer (score 54):

If anybody wants to make it run on local machine then
adding this to server `REPO/.hg/hgrc` will do the work:

```
[web]
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
```

as described at [this site](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Allow_pushing_to_the_repository).

Comment: I have tested allow_push = * or <anotheruser> both still giving me authentication failure

Answer (score 3):

It *is* strange that you can run `hg outgoing` but not `hg push` since it is my understanding that they both authenticate in the same way.

Unfortunately I'm not a hgweb expert. Please mail to the [Mercurial list](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MailingLists) (mercurial@mercurial-scm.org) and/or come online in IRC (`#mercurial` on `irc.freenode.net`). There will be many more people to help you there. IRC is especially good since these things are much easier to debug interactively.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I actually already tried IRC -- without a luck :/ I'll try with the mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

For those with TortoiseHg pushing to a web server (another unauthorized user on another PC):

In TortoiseHg: `File - Settings - (Either globally or just for the current repository - tabs)` then the `Server` settings.
Web Server

```
Push Requires SSL - No
Allow Push - *
```

This does the same thing through the UI as `lukmdo`'s answer above (editing the hgrc file).

Comment: No, lukmdo's answer is server-side. Changing this client-side doesn't help. I have repositories with the first setting undefined (default value), and I manage to push to them without HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it might help someone - I encountered this error for unknown reasons, all permissions were OK, and just restarting apache solved it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a bit different. Password change triggered it... And I had a `repo/.hgrc` and a `repo/.hg/hgrc`. Not sure why, but these were conflicting.

For the record, the cleanest way I've found is to keep a global configuration file (on Windows `C:\Users\<user>\mercurial.ini` or Linux `/home/<user>/.hgrc`) with all the configuration that applies to all repositories (profiles, plugins/extensions, repos, etc), and then per repo, just use something like:

```
[paths]  
default = https://path/to/remote/repo

# any other repo-specific config
```

Why I had another repo-specific mercurial config file, I don't know -- now everything is cleaned up and working nicely.

Comment: I was having the same issue :P

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after changing my bitbucket password, then although I used SourceTree to manage my password and I changed it globaly, one repo however had my old password hard-coded in `REPO/.hg/hgrc` changed the line and all works again

Answer (score 0):

My solution!
If your are on Windows OS, you need to edit folder properties. Read/write permission.

[image]

Very Important!!
Dont forget turn off the web server, edit folder properties and turn on again the web server tortoiseHG