# Mercurial push --new-branch. abort: authorization failed

Tags: apache, mercurial, repository

I have the same problem as [Mercurial push, abort: authorization failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946745/mercurial-push-abort-authorization-failed) however I do not have control over any permissions. I am able to access the repository from a web browser and hg outgoing is successful. I have also tried resetting my password with no change.

The command:

```
$ hg push --new-branch --debug --traceback -f > pushlog.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 87, in _runcatch
  return _dispatch(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 684, in _dispatch
  cmdpats, cmdoptions)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 466, in runcommand
  ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 738, in _runcommand
  return checkargs()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 692, in checkargs
  return cmdfunc()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 681, in <lambda>
  d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 458, in check
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 4333, in push
  if not c.sub(s).push(opts.get('force')):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/subrepo.py", line 524, in push
  return self._repo.push(other, force)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1535, in push
  ret = remote.unbundle(cg, remote_heads, 'push')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/wireproto.py", line 300, in unbundle
  ret, output = self._callpush("unbundle", cg, heads=heads)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 199, in _callpush
  r = self._call(cmd, data=fp, headers=headers, **args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 169, in _call
  fp = self._callstream(cmd, **args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 120, in _callstream
  raise util.Abort(_('authorization failed'))
Abort: authorization failed
abort: authorization failed
```

The log:

```
pushing to https://host/hg/myProject
using https://host/hg/myProject
sending capabilities command
using auth.TR.* for authentication
host certificate matched fingerprint 

f4:57:8a:83:46:9a:d1:eb:7a:c6:58:ac:dd:ea:ed:36:42:ee:2c:56
using auth.TR.* for authentication
http auth: user wilson.droter, password ********
using auth.TR.* for authentication
host certificate matched fingerprint f4:57:8a:83:46:9a:d1:eb:7a:c6:58:ac:dd:ea:ed:36:42:ee:2c:56
pushing subrepo subProject to http://host/hg/subProject
using http://host/hg/subProject
sending capabilities command
using auth.TR.* for authentication
host certificate matched fingerprint f4:57:8a:83:46:9a:d1:eb:7a:c6:58:ac:dd:ea:ed:36:42:ee:2c:56
using auth.TR.* for authentication
http auth: user wilson.droter, password ********
using auth.TR.* for authentication
mercurial.int.thomsonreuters.com certificate matched fingerprint f4:57:8a:83:46:9a:d1:eb:7a:c6:58:ac:dd:ea:ed:36:42:ee:2c:56
query 1; heads
sending batch command
using auth.TR.* for authentication
http auth: user wilson.droter, password ********
using auth.TR.* for authentication
host certificate matched fingerprint f4:57:8a:83:46:9a:d1:eb:7a:c6:58:ac:dd:ea:ed:36:42:ee:2c:56
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
2 changesets found
list of changesets:
877b46d2cc15a8d0a5ea3a6879a5eea14af87c0f
52cabd379e04b56af0d44ba3d3673764d6de9b9e
bundling: 1/2 changesets (50.00%)
bundling: 2/2 changesets (100.00%)
bundling: 1/2 manifests (50.00%)
bundling: 2/2 manifests (100.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/hadoop.conf 1/50 files (2.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/hadoop_archive.log 2/50 files (4.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar 3/50 files (6.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar 4/50 files (8.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar 5/50 files (10.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar 6/50 files (12.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar 7/50 files (14.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar 8/50 files (16.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar 9/50 files (18.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar 10/50 files (20.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar 11/50 files (22.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar 12/50 files (24.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar 13/50 files (26.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar 14/50 files (28.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar 15/50 files (30.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 16/50 files (32.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar 17/50 files (34.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar 18/50 files (36.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar 19/50 files (38.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.1.2.jar 20/50 files (40.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.2.jar 21/50 files (42.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2.jar 22/50 files (44.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.2.jar 23/50 files (46.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/hadoop_archive.log 24/50 files (48.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar 25/50 files (50.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar 26/50 files (52.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar 27/50 files (54.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar 28/50 files (56.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar 29/50 files (58.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar 30/50 files (60.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar 31/50 files (62.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar 32/50 files (64.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar 33/50 files (66.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar 34/50 files (68.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar 35/50 files (70.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar 36/50 files (72.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar 37/50 files (74.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar 38/50 files (76.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar 39/50 files (78.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar 40/50 files (80.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/pig-0.10.0-cdh4.1.2.jar 41/50 files (82.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar 42/50 files (84.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar 43/50 files (86.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar 44/50 files (88.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar 45/50 files (90.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar 46/50 files (92.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar 47/50 files (94.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.2.jar 48/50 files (96.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/run_pig.py 49/50 files (98.00%)
bundling: py_util/hadoop/run_pig.py.orig 50/50 files (100.00%)
sending unbundle command
sending 23785866 bytes
using auth.TR.* for authentication
sending: 64/46456 kb (0.14%)
...
sending: 23228/46456 kb (50.00%)
http auth: user wilson.droter, password ********
using auth.TR.* for authentication
mercurial.int.thomsonreuters.com certificate matched fingerprint f4:57:8a:83:46:9a:d1:eb:7a:c6:58:ac:dd:ea:ed:36:42:ee:2c:56
sending: 23292/46456 kb (50.14%)
...
sending: 46456/46456 kb (100.00%)
```

The push works for a small change to a text file. I think the problem is with adding files.
Do I need to get permissions changed or is there another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get permissions changed.  You have write permission to the `.hg/store/...` files that already exist, which is why you can change that file, but probably not write permissions to the `.hg/store` directory itself so you can't create new files.

You need to make sure your user or group on that server has rwx access to all the files and directories from the repository directory on down.  If it's group access that's letting you in she may need to set the sticky group bit too.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to get my permissions changed.